# Intercept (using Python) data being written to a file from another process

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, intercept

I am working on something where this could come in handy in the future.

Does anyone know of a way I can intercept data (using Python) being written to a file (via some other language/process)?

I would know the path of the file I want to intercept and I preferably want to find a solution that would work on Windows.  I know `watchdog` can watch for file changes but my goal would be to intercept the write before it touches the file.

For example they I have the following script running on my computer that just constantly writes to a file:

```
import time
filename = "testfile"
i = 1
while True:
    with open(filename, 'a') as out:
        out.write(str(i) + '\n')
        time.sleep(1)
        i += 1
```

**Note:** This is just an example. The data I want to intercept is not being written with Python. I don't know what it is written with.

In another script, I want to intercept everything being written to `testfile`.

I don't believe this is possible but I figured I would ask.

Comment: [This snippet](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578882-monitor-progress-of-file-descriptors-of-another-pr/) seems relevant. My *ideal* approach to this problem would be to, when this program is activated, covertly replace the tracked file with some mechanism that makes the file descriptor point to the current program, and act as a man-in-the-middle, which might be more possible.

Comment: Not that code you supplied won't actually update your file unless you `close()` or `flush()` it.

Comment: I haven't needed to do this but I think that's going to be OS-specific and will require admin rights for Windows and/or replacing file system components to add the hooks you need.  Detecting changes is very different since that's just listening for standard Windows events used by directory viewers like Explorer and choose file controls.

Comment: @FilipMłynarski I had the `while` in the wrong spot thank you.

Comment: @DaveS I agree. I can easily hook to a windows change event if I was just waiting for changes but this is more complicated. That is why I am not sure if this is possible (though man in the middle is an option). Linux can use pipes but Windows is difficult.  This dives more into how Windows implements their file writing and if that stream could be intercepted (with admin access)

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy That could work. Though it could run into issues if the intercepted software tries creating a file if one is not found.  It is definitely a viable solution compared to what I am asking :)

Comment: I wonder if you could inject code into the other process to add wrappers around whatever API calls it's using for the file I/O?   Otherwise, maybe a filter driver? - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/introduction-to-file-system-filter-drivers

Comment: @DaveS Those filters drivers could work. I will look into it over the weekend. It looks like those filter drivers may be what antivirus software uses which could work.

Answer (score 0):

Using os.walk you can make a list of how many files you have in your whole directory and then keep checking it and cross reference it with a previous variable that says what the file count is, and when there is a difference you can open it using os.open.

Comment: There is no way to "intercept" a file that has not been created

Comment: This requires that the file does not exist, and even if we find when the file is created there would be no way to intercept the data. Meaning `watchdog` would be a better solution than this for this type of scenerio.