# Python: capturing all writes to a file in memory

Tags: python

Is there some way to "capture" all attempted writes to a particular file `/my/special/file`, and instead write that to a `BytesIO` or `StringIO` object instead, or some other way to get that output without actually writing to disk?

The use case is: there's a 'handler' function, whose contract is that it should write its output to `/my/special/file`. I don't have any control over this `handler` function -- I don't write it, I don't know its contents and I can't change its contents, and the contract cannot change. I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
# 'output' has whatever 'handler' has written to `/my/special/file`
output = handler.run(data)
```

Even if this is an odd request, I'd like to be able to do this even with a 'hackier' answer.

EDIT: my code (and `handler`) will be invoked many times on a lot of chunks of data, so performance (both latency and throughput) are important.

Thanks.

Comment: [Relevant, but doesn't directly answer the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55716275/intercept-using-python-data-being-written-to-a-file-from-another-process). Some of the comments on that post might also be relevant.

Comment: My ideal approach to this problem would be to copy `/my/special/file` to somewhere else, and use [`pipes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pipes.html) or something to plant a "dummy" file that pipes attempted writes directly into your program. Your program would then act as a man-in-the-middle.

Comment: What OS do you use? Is `mkfifo` available on your platform?

Comment: Is this "handler function" a Python module you're calling from your own Python code, or is it just some arbitrary program running on your system?

Comment: Definitely agree on `mkfifo` if available, and [named pipes](https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2156) (related) are worth a look

Comment: You could use the `unittest.mock` library to mock the handler.

Comment: Interesting -- I have a few questions about this:

If I make a symlink from `/my/special/file` to a FIFO and have my code read from that FIFO, would performance suffer from OS overhead of writing to / reading from the pipe?

Would performance be comparable to 'handler' actually returning the data (against the contract, of course)?

Would using a FIFO like this be appreciably different from writing to and reading from a file?

Comment: Steve's question is relevant - if the `handler` is in Python code, you could intercept calls to whatever function it is calling to open the file or write to it, even if you don't have access to the function itself. If the handler is calling some pre-compiled, non-Python code that's actually writing the file, you'll need to set a hack that's likely specific to your OS. It's the "without actually writing to disk" part that will be really hard here, since most solutions would still involve a write to disk. If you don't mind the writes, but just want the content, consider reading while writing?

Comment: Yes, `handler` is Python code. Seems like I could use a mocking library to intercept calls to `open('/my/special/file')` to return a file-like object that I have access to (when my code invokes  `handler`). I'm curious about what the performance overhead of intercepting these calls would be -- performance is important in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking about code in your own Python program, you could monkey-patch the built in `open` function before that code gets called.  Here's a really stupid example, but it shows that you can do this.  This causes code that thinks it's writing to a file to instead write into an in-memory buffer.  The calling code then prints what the foreign code wrote to the file:

```
import io

# The function you don't have access to that writes to a file
def foo():
    f = open("/tmp/foo", "w")
    f.write("blahblahblah\n")
    f.close()

# The buffer to contain the captured text
capture_buffer = ""

# My silly file-like object that only handles write(str) and close()
class MyFileClass:
    def write(self, str):
        global capture_buffer
        capture_buffer += str
    def close(self):
        pass

# patch open to return a MyFileClass instance
def my_open2(*args, **kwargs):
    return MyFileClass()
open = my_open2


# Call the target function
foo()

# Print what the function wrote to "the file"
print(capture_buffer)
```

Result:

```
blahblahblah
```

Sorry for not spending more time with this.  Just showing you it's possible.  As others say, a mocking module might be the way to go to not have to grow your own thing here.  I don't know if they allow access to what is written.  I guess they must.  Such a module is just going to do a better job of what I've shown here.

If your program does other file IO with `open`, or whichever method the mystery code uses to open the file, you'd check the incoming path and only return your special object if it was the one path you're interested in.  Otherwise, you could just call the original `open`, which you could stash away under another name.

Comment: Very interesting. Thank you for the illustration. I think this would work. I'll see what other options I'll have available, and whether a mocking library is the right way to go, but this seems like the right approach.

Comment: what about `file`?